# Difference between executing .sh/.bash program with sh/bash and executing it directly

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, sh

If we have a program start.sh, we can execute it with the sh start.sh. But we could execute it giving permission with chmod and run ./start.sh in the command line. What is the difference between those two ways of executing a bash/sh script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both execute shell script but there is some little difference:

`sh` will use will use the sh interpreter even if a differenter interpreter was indicated in the begining of the file like `#!/bin/bash` this can be useful if you want your script to be executed using always the same interpreter

for `./start.sh` the shell will try to execute as an executable file so the script need a shebang like `#!/bin/bash` so `./start.sh` is more flexible since you can use the interpreter you want

Comment: You don't _need_ a shebang actually. `./start.sh` will still work even without one. I was just testing and I can't quite figure out if it runs using whatever the default `$SHELL` is or not. When I was running a bash shell, it ran with `bash` but from a `zsh` and `dash` shell, it ran with `/bin/sh`. In any case, the main point is that even without a shebang, an executable file containing shell commands can be run with `./script.sh`.